# merging files in numerical order ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sorting

Hy everyone!

I have a list of 100 numerical files `1.txt 2.txt...n.txt`
I want to merge their content to an `output.txt` , but would like to keep their numerical order, such as my output file would contain
`output of file 1.txt output of file 2.txt  output of file n.txt`
Using both `tail` or `cat` gives a file in which the output is not in numerical order.

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are you using `cat`? Is it `cat *` (or `cat *.txt`)? What is your shell? For Zsh: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38368/108618).

Comment: another option is to use `ls -v`, as in: `cat \`ls -v *.txt\` > out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) might help you there. I assume that you only wanted the *files* to be sorted, not the *lines* within files:

```
cat {1..n}.txt >> output.txt
```

If your filenames have leading zero(s), simply use `{001..n}` instead.